# How to disable back/forward cache in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-cache

I am trying to figure out how to disable the `cache` in my 'react' app, but when it loads doesn't execute any `javascript` code.

I expect that when I click on my 'react' application, all the JS code will run and **no-cache** will be loaded.

- I hope someone can help me and thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Comment: Let me know if it solved your question @Alejandro Gabriel

Answer (score 2):

I was just editing to understand, but maybe I can help, I think there is an effective way to disable `back/forward cache` and prevent page contents as (*html*, *css*, *javascript*, *images*, *etc*) from being served by the back-forward cache and it is using the **Cache-Control HTTP header**.

Can work checking your web server to send this in the response headers of your page or `HTML` document, based on *[MDN Web Docs cache-control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)*.

HTTP 1.1. Allowed values = PUBLIC | PRIVATE | NO-CACHE | NO-STORE.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

No need to send it for all the assets (*css*, *images*, *scripts*, *etc*) which’ll prevent them from getting cached normally, because the idea is to just avoid the browser `back/forward cache`, maybe is your issue.

- Other option could be using '**unload**' or '**beforeunload**' events with empty event listeners, if your issue is about the `DOM`, this information also could help '[window.onunload.onbeforeunload](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded)'.

Answer (score -1):

You need to go out of your way to `cache` things in react by using things like:

Hooks --> **useMemo()** and **useCallback()**

It may be that the caching is happening in the browser.  If you are in `chrome` for example.

- Try inspecting the page with DevTools
- Clicking the refesh button
- Clicking to empty cache and hard reload

If this does not work, for more help, can you post the section of code you think is caching?

Comment: sadly this does not help me with the problem i'm having :c

Comment: Are you sure the javascript file is properly called into the file with a script or link tag?